# A question regarding inequalities and some binomial theorem

Tags: real-analysis

Let $m, n \in \mathbb N$ with $m<n$ show that $ \frac {1}{m^k} \binom{m}{k} <\frac {1}{n^k} \binom{n}{k} \leq \frac{1}{k!} \leq \frac{1}{2^{k-1}}$ for all $k = 2, ... , m$

Now in order to start this question off I've decided to expand the binomial for the $ \frac {1}{m^k} \binom{m}{k} <\frac {1}{n^k} \binom{n}{k}$ following parts and it's left me with $\frac {1}{m^k}(\frac {m(m-1)*...*(m-k+1)}{k!}) $ and the same for the one with n in place of the m. Now I'm not sure where to go from here or what I should do.

Answer (score 1):

Idea: Induction over $k$ could help here

Verify the statement for $k=2$

Assume that for a certain $k$ you have  $ \frac {1}{m^k} \binom{m}{k} <\frac {1}{n^k} \binom{n}{k} \leq \frac{1}{k!} \leq \frac{1}{2^{k-1}}$

and prove that

$ \frac {1}{m^{k+1}} \binom{m}{k+1} <\frac {1}{n^{k+1}} \binom{n}{k+1} \leq \frac{1}{(k+1)!} \leq \frac{1}{2^{k}}$

Comment: For the case that k = 2 (just for the first 2 terms in the inequality) is it sufficient for me to substitute k = 2 in. Then I've simplified the answer to $\frac{m-1}{2m} \leq \frac{n-1}{2n}$ then by doing some re-arrangement I can show $m \leq n$ which is what's in the question so this statement would be true?

Comment: Did $m<n$ lead to $ \frac {1}{m^2} \binom{m}{2} <\frac {1}{n^2} \binom{n}{2} \leq \frac{1}{2} $ ? In case yes, continue with the proof for $k+1$

Comment: I evaluated the both binomials and got $\frac{m-1}{2m}$ and $\frac{n-1}{2n}$ I then just showed that their limit as they went to infinity was a half so that they must be $\leq$ a half and with the 2 things I'd already calculated I equated them and showed that m $\le$ n which is what's given in the question so it must be true. Sorry if I'm missing a vital part here. I'm not great with showing/proving things so I'm just trying to ask for help to improve